# JQuery Sortable Accordion moving to top with code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am building a sortable accordion with jquery which works perfectly fine but I want it so when someone clicks on on of the items in the accordion and it opens up that it is automatically moved to the top of the list without the person having to drag it to the top. Is that possible to code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `prepend` to move the element to the top of list. The HTML is taken from jQuery UI's demo page, with the addition of this line here that moves the element to the top of the list:

```
$("#accordion h3").click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('div').prependTo('#accordion');
});
```

Have a look at the live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4jkvg/1/